# Fetch single value from Firebase against id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having problem while fetching a value "rate_perltr" against user id I couldn't fetch so far, I have tried all way but still getting error.

```
    myDatabaseRateFetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customers");
```

customerName.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

```
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            myDatabaseRateFetch.orderByChild("cust_id").equalTo(7040).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try
                    {
                        String ratePerLtr = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        Rate rate = dataSnapshot.getValue(Rate.class);
                        rate_fetch = rate.getRate_perltr();

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+databaseError.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            rate.setText(Html.fromHtml(" "+ String.valueOf(rate_fetch) +""));
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Rate Model Class
package com.example.wms;

public class Rate {

```
private double rate_perltr;

public Rate()
{

}

public Rate(double rate_perltr) {
    this.rate_perltr = rate_perltr;
}

public double getRate_perltr() {
    return rate_perltr;
}

public void setRate_perltr(double rate_perltr) {
    this.rate_perltr = rate_perltr;
}
```

Comment: show me your java code

Comment: Please post the code for your Rate Model.

Comment: Please add the content of your `Rate` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have added all the thing which you asked in proper way kindly see this...

Comment: @HussainAbbas I added my all code.

Comment: @VenkataNarayana see code please

Comment: @hamzaahmed check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with your `Rate` Model. It is unable to map your firebase data to your `Rate` model.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 private void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : datasnapshot.getChildren){
       Rate rateFetch = snapshot.getValue(Rate.class);
       rateF[0] = ratefetch.getRate_perltr();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you just want to fetch the result of a field from your firebase table, you can do this in your onDataChange() method

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Rate r = new Rate(); //   

    try {
      r.setVar((String) dataSnapshot.child("var").getValue()); //var is the firebase field
    } catch (Exception e) {
      r.setVar("whatever you want here");
    }
}
```

If you want to fill a model with the firebase result, ensure that instance variables names matches the fields in the firebase table then you can do this:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
   for(DataSnapshot snapshot : datasnapshot.getChildren){
      Rate rate = snapshot.getValue(Rate.class);
      //then get any variable you want from rate
   }
}
```